# while running code it shows Unexpected token

Tags: reactjs, firebase

import React from 'react';

const Login = (props) => {

```
const { email, setEmail, password, setPassword, handleLogin, handleSignup, hasAccount, setHasAccount, emailError, passwordError } = props;

return (
    <section className="login">
        <div className="loginContainer">
            <label>Username</label>
            <input
                type="text"
                autoFocus
                required
                value={email}
                onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
            />
            <p className="errorMsg">{emailError}</p>
            <input
                type="password"
                required
                value={password}
                onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
            />

            <p className="errorMsg">{passwordError}</p>
            <div className="btnContainer">
            
                {hasAccount ? (
                     <>
                        <button onClick={handleLogin}> Sign in </button>
                        <p>
                            Don't have an account ?
                            <span onClick={() => setHasAccount(!hasAccount)}>Sign up</span>
                        </p>
                    </>
                    
                ) : (
                    <>
                        <button onClick={handleLogin}> Sign up </button>
                        <p>
                            Has an account ?
                            <span onClick={() => setHasAccount(!hasAccount)}>Sign in</span>
                        </p>
                    </>
                )}
            </div>
        </div>
        
    </section>
)
```

}

export default Login;

O/p
Error shown is:-
Error in ./src/Login.js
Syntax error: D:/React/todos-list/src/Login.js: Unexpected token (30:26)

28 |
29 |                     {hasAccount ? (

> 30 |                          <>
> |                           ^
> 31 |                              Sign in 
> 32 |
>
> 33 |                                 Don't have an account ?

@ ./src/App.js 20:13-31

Comment: You have an empty tag. `<>`

Comment: how can I fixed that

Comment: Make it an actual element, like a div. I forget if react allows multiple children without a wrapper, might try deleting it.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).